# Android x86 on KVM-QEMU issue with the sound

Tags: qemu, xubuntu, pulse-audio, android-x86, virtual-machine-manager

My OS is Xubuntu 18.04. I recently installed qemu-kvm as well as Virtual Machine Manager. I created a virtual machine for Android x86 7.1 using the VM wizard. Everything works fine with the default options but one issue with the sound (the model of the sound device in the vm is ich6).
Every time that there is a sound coming from the Android vm the volume of my computer goes up to 100% (Xubuntu uses Pulseaudio).
If at the same time I am listening to any other source of audio, let's say Youtube for instance, the volume doesn't get really increased, although it can be seen in the audio mixer that it is at 100%. If I turn it down and Android vm makes a sound the volume goes up 100% again.
I haven't found any comment similar to this anywhere. What can I do to prevent the virtual machine from increasing the volume that much?
Thank you very much in advance.